# Mysql workbench users

Tags: mysql

Im using mysql workbench to manage the database of an application am creating. The problem is i have a table called user which contains the usernames and passwords of all my users but they cant login  till i go into the mysql workbench server administration and add them one by one under Users and Privileges again before they can login.

I was wondering if there was an easier or faster way to do this. i have over a 100 users to add.

Answer (score 4):

You need to run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` for any changes to the `mysql.user` database to take effect.

MySQL Workbench will do this automatically when adding a user, but if you're manually adding people to the `mysql.user` database, then you'll need to manually run the `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` SQL too.

From [the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html),

> **PRIVILEGES**
>
> Reloads the privileges from the grant tables in the mysql database.

Comment: im using the INSERT INTO statement to add the bulk users to user table, am still unable to login even after running the flush privileges. it just says 0 rows affected... :/

Comment: Any reason why you're creating users directly into the table rather than using CREATE USER (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html) and GRANT (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)? And just to clarify, we're talking about MySQL users in the `mysql.user` table right? (Not users for your application or anything)

Comment: nah...i thought that there might be a way that the users from the user table of my application's database to login. sorry im new to this, didnt even know about the mysql.user, how do i add the users to that? 

THANKS

Comment: hey can i use phpmyadmin with mysql workbench to do this? do i also have to install xampp?

Comment: phpmyadmin is separate to Workbench, it's probably best to use one or the other, as they both do the same thing (there may be some feature difference, but essentially they're trying to do the same job). Just that workbench runs as a desktop application, and phpmyadmin has to be run on a server with PHP installed. As for your users, if they're application users do they really need direct database access? I suspect not. If you really do want to add users who can login to the MySQL database you can use CREATE USER and GRANT queries to do it (see the docs links in my other comment).

Comment: im making an application for users to signin and out and before they can do that(update a row) they need the insert, update and select privileges of the schema.

Comment: The usual way to do this is to have just one MySQL user called "[your_app_name]" with the relevant permissions. Then you're application uses it's own user table to control access to the application, and the one MySQL user to access the database. If you just want people to be able to login to your app, they don't need their own MySQL account.

Comment: oh thanks for the explanation. can you please show me the process how this is done

Comment: i really need to finish this project by tuesday so please try and help me out. thanks

Comment: Odd, I created my user WITH Workbench and was still having problems, manually flushing privileges fixed it. It was a phpMyAdmin upgrade on a newer mac (migrated form older mac) so perhaps something else was amiss.